# Visualize x-y-z position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visualization

I use a Kinect SDK V2 sensor to capture point cloud.The output of my program is a double array that contains X-Y-Z position points for every frame(0,0,0 is the center of the sensor). Now i would like to visualize the data for example for one frame. Is any fast/easy way just to visualize the data?Any .dll?

P.S:I tried with Unity but it was to difficult and  time consuming for me.I thought that code does not need it because question it too general(if code would be helpful i could upload parts).

Thank you